# Error creating bean with name 'memberSv' defined in com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv defined

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am a student studying java. I want to make a simple membership registration using Spring boot mongoDB, but an error occurs and I ask a question.
my source code

1. MemberDTO

   ```
    public class MemberDTO {

        @Id
        private String memberId;
        private String memberPwd;
        private String memberName;
        private String memberEName;
        private String memberCompany;
        private String memberPhone;
        private String memberZipCode;
        private String memberAddress;
        private String memberAddressDetail;
        private String memberAuth;
        @CreatedDate
        private Date createdDate;
    }
   ```
2. MemberController

   ```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/member")
    public class MemberController {


        @Autowired
        private MemberSv memberSv;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO)
        {
            memberSv.membersave(memberDTO);
            return "join_form";
        }
    }
   ```
3. MemberSv

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface MemberSv extends MongoRepository<MemberDTO, String> {
        MemberDTO membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO);
    }
   ```
4. MemberSvImp

   ```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class MemberSvImp {

        @Autowired
        private MemberSv memberSv;

        public MemberDTO membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO) {
            return memberSv.save(memberDTO);
        }
    }
   ```
5. Spring boot main method

   ```
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses =com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class AccountProjectApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AccountProjectApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
   ```
6. Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberController': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberSv'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberSv' defined in com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on AccountProjectApplication:     Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.example.accountproject.documents.MemberDTO com.example.accountproject.models.interfaces.MemberSv.membersave(com.example.accountproje ct.documents.MemberDTO)! Reason: No property membersave found for type MemberDTO! Did you mean 'memberName'?; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property membersave found for type MemberDTO! Did you mean 'memberName'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is you cannot save the `MemberDTO` as it is through `MongoRepository`. You need to persist the entity object rather than a POJO.

You need to add a MongoDB configuration By annotating the configuration class with `@EnableMongoRepositories`

And finally, you need to make sure that you have created a [collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-collection) (the MongoDB equivalent of a table in SQL) in MongoDB to persists the Member [Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-document) (the MongoDB equivalent of a record in a table in SQL)

1. MongoDB configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.accountproject.models"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class MongoDBConfiguration{

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}") // set host in application.properties file
    private String mongoHost; 
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}") // set port in application.properties file
    private int mongoPort;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}") // set DB name in application.properties file
    private String mongoDatabase;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.user}") // set user in application.properties file
    private String mongoUser;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}") // set password in application.properties file
    private String mongoPassword;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, mongoDatabase, mongoPassword.toCharArray());
        ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDatabase);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Autowired MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

And remove the `@EnableMongoRepositories` Annotation in the `AccountProjectApplication` class

2. introduce a new Model class for the Entity `Member`(Let's say the collection name is 'register')

```
 @Document(collection = 'register')
 public class Member{
     @Id
     private String memberId;
     private String memberPwd;
     private String memberName;
     private String memberEName;
     private String memberCompany;
     private String memberPhone;
     private String memberZipCode;
     private String memberAddress;
     private String memberAddressDetail;
     private String memberAuth;
     @CreatedDate
     private Date createdDate;

     //getters and setters

}
```

3. MemberController

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/member")
 public class MemberController {


     @Autowired
     private MemberSvImp memberService;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO)
     {
         memberService.membersave(memberDTO);
         return "join_form";
     }
 }
```

4. Service layer

```
@Service 
@Transactional 
public class MemberSvImp {

    @Autowired
    private MemberSv memberSv;

    public Member membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO){
        Member member = new Member();
        //set member attributes through memberDTO
        //ex : member.setMemberName=memeberDTO.getMemeberName(); 
        return memberSv.save(member);
    }

}
```

5. Repository Class's Base Entity should be changed to `Member`

```
@Repository
public interface MemberSv extends MongoRepository<Member, String> {
    //you can call save(Entity) or saveAndFlush(Entity) of JPARespository directly without defining any custom methods to save new member. 
}
```

**SUGGESTION** : Better if you can rename the repository and service class to  show their purpose

MemberSv -> MemberRespository

MemberSvImp - > MemberService

Comment: the way i want
in MemberController
I was wondering how to use membersave of MemberRespository interface .

Comment: @DBK you should inject `MemberSvImp` in there instead of `MemberSv`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

where is your configuration file for setting up credentials??

Comment: https://github.com/HeoJinHo/accountProject
this project github TankYou!! Please